# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{-n} =1-x $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Given that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1 - x}$$

What is?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{-n} $$

Comment: If $\lvert x\rvert > 1$, it's $\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Comment: Is, for instance, $1/a + 1/b$ the same as $1/(a+b)$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1 - x}$ when $|x|<1$

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I think a good followup question to @Randall's insightful comment is: Why would you *expect* it to be that?

Answer (score 2):

First, when the series converges, 
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n} = \frac {x}{1-x}.$

And,
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} x^{-n} = \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac {1}{x}\right)^n = \frac {\frac {1}{x}}{1 - \frac {1}{x}}.$

Simplify, $\frac {1}{x - 1}.$

Regarding convergence, 
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}$ converges when $|x| < 1.$

Similarly,
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac {1}{x}\right)^n$ converges when $|\frac {1}{x}| < 1$ or $|x| > 1.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}$ converge than it can't converge  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{-n}$.
Anyway if $\mid x\mid > 1$ than we have
 $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{-n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{x}{x-1}$$

Comment: There's a very serious caveat here, namely that if $\sum x^n$ converges then $\sum x^{-n}$ does not.

Comment: Of course they can't converge at the same time. @MathLover Corrected

Comment: @user296602 I've edited the question with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1 - x}$, it must mean that $|x|<1$, which means that $\frac{1}{|x|}>1$, so that the second sum diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$.

If $|x| < 1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac 1{1-x}$. So if $|x| < 1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac x{1-x}$.  But if $|x|\ge 1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n$ does not converge.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{-n} = \sum_{n}^{\infty} (\frac 1x)^n$.  So if $|\frac 1x| < 1$ (or in other words $|x|> 1$) then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{-n}= \frac {\frac 1x}{1-\frac 1x} = \frac 1{x-1}$ but does not converge if $|x|\le 1$.